# Where are external libraries in a jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libraries, decompiler, jd-gui

I recently wanted to decompile a jar and edit the contents, so I used jd-gui to decompile it, I saved the project, and I unzipped it. I opened the project in IntelliJ and I was getting a lot of errors for missing types. All the imports that were not built into Java said unknown. Where are these libraries in the jar, and how do I get them out and add them to intellij?

Comment: What are *a lot of errors*? what types are missing, exactly? maybe you can show the structure of your .jar file? this sole plain text question is not enough, for us, to help you. Create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least, hint how to get there.

Comment: Download sk1er's Minecraft Levelhead mod and use jd-gui to decompile it, then open the project in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

An application may have dependencies that are not included in the jar at all. In that case, the user would be expected to install the dependencies themselves.

Comment: Yeah the dependencies are definitely in the Jar because it is a Minecraft mod that you can just drop in to the mods folder, you don't need to install other things. So your suggestion was unhelpful, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @YHDiamond when you have some kind of plugin for an application, the main application will load the extension and care to provide the necessary environment. It should not come at a surprise that a Minecraft mod can use certain classes provided by Minecraft, which are not in the mod’s jar file, as there is no reason why every mod should contain copies of those classes.